# Open-source YouTube-style UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, open-source, ios, youtube, uitableview

Does anyone know of any open-source UITableViewController implementations that are styled like the ones in the youtube application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the three20 project: https://github.com/facebook/three20. If you try the `TTCatalog` demo app, you'll see something much like YouTube's `UITableViewController` implementation.